# What exactly to destroy in "Maintenance Factory" alien building to accomplish a mission?

Tags: x-com-apocalypse

Mission briefing shows some kind of towers. "Tower" tops are exploding when receive couple of shots from Devastator Cannon. I believe what my operatives made all of those "towers" to explode, but there was still no "building disabled" message. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try ending your turn (if you're playing turn-based), or wait a few seconds if you're playing in real-time mode. If you still don't get the building disabled message, you've probably missed one.

Comment: Yup, i finally found undestroyed one.